# How to deal with when soft keyboard show in my custom view?

Tags: android, ondraw

I hava a custom view ,in the method onDraw,i drew a random color,the color changed when the soft keyboard show! This is my codes:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    LogUtils.d("onDraw");
    if (null != percentages && percentages.length > 0) {
        canvas.translate(myWidth / 2, myHeight / 2);
        RectF rectF = new RectF(-mRadius, -mRadius, mRadius, mRadius);
        float currentPai = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < percentages.length; i++) {
            Paint arcPaint = new Paint();
            arcPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            //This is my random color!
            int color = Color.rgb(NumberFormatUtils.getRandomInt(255), NumberFormatUtils
                    .getRandomInt(255), NumberFormatUtils.getRandomInt(255));
            arcPaint.setColor(color);
            float targetPai = (float) (percentages[i] * 3.6);
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, currentPai, targetPai, true, arcPaint);
            currentPai = currentPai + targetPai;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to keep color when soft keyboard show,how can i do?Thanks!

Comment: you have to use broadcast for listening to keyboard listener

Comment: And then?I do not want to know whether the keyboard is show or not,i just want to keep the color when keyboard show.If i register the listener but the onDraw will be executed again when keyboard show,i do not know why the keyboard show the customview execute ondraw!

Comment: ya got it but when the keyboard is shown that time all view is created again and that's why onDraw method is called

Comment: How can i prevent it,or any solutions to keep my colors?

Comment: android:isScrollContainer="false"  try this add it in manifest

Comment: sorry,it is invalid,in the top of my activity layout is a edittext,so when i click the edittext,the soft keyboard show,the customview call the ondraw again

Answer (score 0):

I hava solved my question,just add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" in manifest.I hava tried!When added,the method onDraw will not be called when soft keyboard show,But i really do not know why,may be i can learn all properties of the windowSoftInputMode!

Comment: You should not combine multiple "adjust...". 
The setting must be one of the values listed in the following table, or a combination of one "state..." value plus one "adjust..." value. Setting multiple values in either group — multiple "state..." values, for example — has undefined results. Individual values are separated by a vertical bar (|).
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element